# How to check emails logs through AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, joomla

I have a Joomla website & it is configured to use AWS-SES for outgoing emails. Is there any way or logging by which I can check all outgoing emails from AWS/Joomla with minimum details like timestamp, sent to email id, subject.

Please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

So while SES doesn't have any fully featured monitoring Suite, you can set SES up to deliver Delivery, Bounce and Complaint Notifications.

With these notifications, you can develop your own application or read the raw notifications that will show you what emails got delivered/bounced/complaints.

Full information on these notifications is available on the AWS Documentation:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/notifications.html

Comment: @Padeez- Could you please tell what all details can I get? I am mainly looking for email id to which mail is sent, timestamp & subject.

Comment: You get the following in a JSON encoded format:

Timestamp,
Message ID, 
Reporting MTA,
Destination,
Source Address, 

You can see an example here:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/ses-delivery-notifications/

Comment: @Paddez- I have got the timestamp, email id to which mail is sent but cannot get the subject of the email. Unsure if that feature exists.

Answer (score 2):

You can publish your email sending events to an Amazon Kinesis Data Firehose delivery stream. This will take metadata from your sent emails and write it to an S3 bucket, which should produce your desired log.

Amazon has a tutorial on implementing this process at the link below.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/event-publishing-kinesis-analytics.html

Comment: One should be aware that is ridiculously complex. It took me two hours to realize that Kinesis Data Delivery stream must be Direct PUT type, even though Amazon SES is not listed as compatible service for it, and do not create Kinesis Data stream. This step, as many others, just skipped in the tutorial. Then, S3 started to save JSON messages with Access Denied, with no hints from where it is originated.  I gave up here.